# How to add PHP code to .tpl file

Tags: php, smarty

I need to display some external data from php file to .tpl file. For this I want to include php file to .tpl file. I have tried folllowing code to display php file content to tpl.

```
{php} include('custom_code.php'); {/php}
```

but on page output was `include('custom_code.php');`

Comment: And your Smarty delimiters are `{}`? What if they're `{{}}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{php}` has been deprecated. Have a look at [Extending Smarty With Plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl).

put the follwing in `…/plugins/function.yourplugin.php`:

```
<?php
function smarty_function_yourplugin(array $params, Smarty_Template_Instance) {
    include 'your_other_file.php';
}
```

and use in your template:

```
{yourplugin}
```

Comment: thanks rodneyrehm for solution, I will try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a best practise guide on smarty homepage. #1 is Do not embed PHP!

http://www.smarty.net/best_practices

Try this: `{include_php file="/path/to/somefile.php"}`

But notice:

```
{include_php} is deprecated from Smarty, use registered plugins 
to properly insulate presentation from the application code. 
As of Smarty 3.1 the {include_php} tags are only available 
from SmartyBC.
```

So best way is to write a smarty plugin as explained by rodneyrehm

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add PHP code to the template. It will make whole idea of templates spoiled.

You have to add PHP code to controller, not template.